# Nginx - Routing to a different app server endpoint than matching locaion

Tags: nginx

If I have the following inbound url: `/blog/mailchimp.xml` but I want to serve the endpoint from the app server of `/blog/atom.xml` and I don't want to do a rewrite, what is the best way to write this rule for nginx?

Comment: Please share your nginx configuration. Your question has too little details on the actual problem and therefore it cannot be answered.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use a rewrite then you should be able to return a 301 or 302 to where you want to go. I can't test this right now but I don't see why it wouldn't work

```
location /blog/mailchimp.xml {
    return 302 $scheme://YOUR-SITE/blog/atom.xml;
}
```